# Finding the determinant that depends on an order of operations

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

A and B are $3\times3$ matrices. Given det $A = -4$ and det $B = 2$

Finding the $det(2A^{-1}B$ )

With the order of operations would I invert first, multiply by two then multiply by $B$, which is also two.

$(2/1)(1/-4)(2/1) = 4/-4 = -1$

Does that seem right?

Comment: Are there any matrices in this problem?

Comment: no matrices given. Just det A and det B. I'll update question

Comment: So why is it tagged with "matrices", and why mention determinants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not right.

If $X$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, then
$$
\det(2X)=2^3\det X
$$
If $\det Y\ne0$, then $\det(Y^{-1})=(\det Y)^{-1}$. Finally, $\det(XY)=\det X\cdot\det Y$.

Put the pieces together.

Comment: So then, 

$2^3 * (1/-4) * 2 = -4$ Order of multiplication doesn't matter because of association...

Comment: @10111110 More precisely, because of commutativity of multiplication of numbers. For instance, if $AB\ne BA$, then $A^{-1}B\ne BA^{-1}$, but these two matrices have the same determinant.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are scalars, then $2A^{-1}B$ is also a scalar, and we can speak of the determinant of the scalar as being itself. Hence $\det(2A^{-1}B) = 2(\det A)^{-1}\det B=2\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \cdot 2=-1.$

If $A$ and $B$ are scalar $n\times n$ matrices, then instead we have $\det(2A^{-1}B) = 2(\det A)^{-1}\det B=2\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{4^n}\right) \cdot 2^n=-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.$

If you mean that $A$ and $B$ are matrices with $\det A=-4$ and $\det B=2$, then yes, it's as you say, we have $\det(2A^{-1}B) = 2(\det A)^{-1}\det B=2\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \cdot 2=-1.$